# group by date and max of a version query mistake

Tags: mysql, sql, database

this is my current sql query :

```
SELECT `room_id`, `target_date`, `rate_per_room`, `max_room`, MAX(`version`)
    FROM `t0311_room_rate`
        WHERE `room_id` = ?
           AND `target_date` >= ?
           AND `target_date` is not null 
           GROUP BY `target_date`
           ORDER BY `target_date`
```

These are my sample data

[image]

I should get three records if i query target_date >= today, in which yes, it does.
However, the version and the rate_per_room do not tally.
for instance version 12, i should get 195, but i get 190 instead.

Is there any part that i missed in my query?

Thank you

Comment: `SELECT `room_id`, `target_date`, `rate_per_room`, `max_room`... GROUP BY `target_date`  is invalid SQL.. MySQL can return random results for columns not named in the GROUP BY ... read https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense.  It shouldn't have run.  Which value of rate_per_room will get picked up for target_date 2017-10-01?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want the `MAX(rate_per_room)`.  You should also add your other non-aggregate columns to your `GROUP BY`.  Most RDBMS would make you do this but MySQL is 'special'.

```
SELECT `room_id`, `target_date`, MAX(`rate_per_room`), `max_room`, MAX(`version`)
FROM `t0311_room_rate`
WHERE `room_id` = ?
AND `target_date` >= ?
AND `target_date` is not null 
GROUP BY `room_id`, `target_date`, `max_room`
ORDER BY `target_date`
```

**Edit:**

Since the `MAX(version)` will not always match up with the `MAX(rate_per_room)`, you should get the `MAX(version)` first, then `JOIN` back to the table for the rest of the data:

```
SELECT b.room_id, b.target_date, b.rate_per_room, b.max_room, a.version
FROM (SELECT room_id, MAX(Version) as version
      FROM t0311_room_rate
      GROUP BY room_id) a
INNER JOIN t0311_room_rate b on a.room_id = b.room_id
                            and a.version = b.version
--Add filters as desired
ORDER BY target_date
```

Comment: I still cannot get the rate_per_room for the maximum version of every date.
The version is correct, but the rate_per_room is not correct yet..

Comment: @BrianRuchiadi I mistakenly believed that you wanted the max of each column.  See my edit, this way you identify the `max(version)` for each room, then join back to the table to get all the data associated with the `max(version)`